# Symbol Path Not Found in windbg

Tags: windows, debugging, crash, windbg, dmp

I have set the path as

```
srv*C:\Users\swpapati\Desktop\admintool_crash\pdbs*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

where "C:\Users\swpapati\Desktop\admintool_crash\pdbs" exists and has the local copy of required symbol file values.

On loading the dmp crash file I can see below text on console :-
[image: Crash File Output]

On issuing Command - .reload /f admintool.exe I can get below error as Symbol file not found.
Similar error is obtained on issuing !analyze -v or .reload /f

[image]

The admintool.pdb is present at C:\Users\swpapati\Desktop\admintool_crash\pdbs.
Also I have set the env variable

```
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH = srv*C:\Users\swpapati\Desktop\admintool_crash\pdbs*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

What setting went wrong?

Comment: Microsoft symbol server only contains Microsoft PDBs. What is admintool.exe?

Comment: Yes I agree . admintool.exe is a local application exe of which pdb exists at the path C:\Users\swpapati\Desktop\admintool_crash\pdbs..but it is still not picked up from the local location

Comment: put the PDB for the tool into a different folder: `c:\symbols\AdminTool;srv*c:\Symbols\dl*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;`

Answer (score 0):

> The admintool.pdb is present at C:\Users\swpapati\Desktop\admintool_crash\pdbs

You can't simply put a PDB file into a folder that has a structure of a symbol store.

There are at least 2 solutions:

a) put your own PDBs into the folder using the tool `symstore.exe`. This approach will require learning about how symbol stores are set up and how to use `symstore.exe`.

b) use two different paths, one for the Microsoft symbols and one folder with your own symbols. Commands are like this:

```
.sympath x:\whereever\your\pdbs\are\
.symfix+ x:\whereever\microsoft\symbols\should\go\
```

Note the `+` at the end of a command. It tells WinDbg to use that *in addition* to the existing symbol paths that are already set up.